# Issue populating Textview with data from website via URL

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I'm trying to read a line of text from a URL and display the result in a Textview.

### ISSUE/ERROR:

At present there is no error, the textview is not populated after I execute DownloadWebPage Async task.

### **INVESTIGATIONS**

I believe I may not be calling this correctly, as I can't find any results from my debug calls, in DownloadWebPage. Also my URL has one line of code with two strings, if that makes any difference.

### UPDATE:

In DownloadWebPage my logs commands are not showing in the log files  - weird

### **CODE: ON CREATE:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inbox_list);
       textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);

      // Hashmap for ListView
       inboxList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

       //ASYNC TASK I CREATED
       new DownloadWebPageTask().execute();

      // Another Async Task in my code
       new LoadInbox().execute();


  }
```

### **CODE: AsyncTask for Parsing Data from URL & Setting Data to Textview**

```
 private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";
            for (String url : urls) {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                    InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += s;
                    }

                System.out.println(response);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
        }
    }

    public void readWebpage(View view) {
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.url.com/blah.php" });

    }
```

Comment: Have u checked logcat is there any exception?

Comment: Don't use System.out.println(), it won't print out. Use android.util.Log to print and then check logcat for your prints messages.

Comment: Thanks, I was sure System.out.println & Log.d both print to LogCat.

Comment: By the way, your `AsyncTask` has a strong reference to `textView` which means your UI will remain in memory till network request finishes which is a memory leak.. welcome to Android world :) make the async task static or use weak references.

Comment: Ok the LogCat is showing none of my logs,  Gennadii this is not fun :)